# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 Callable returned a null value

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

Inside my Activity `B` I call an async method called `myASYNC` that gets data from an API (the amount of data is big enough that it takes a few seconds to load all of it). If I click the Android back button that takes me back to activity `A` while the `myASYNC` is still running I get this error and the app crashes:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
    Process: com.hfad.crypto, PID: 9473
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Callable returned a null value. Null values are generally not allowed in 3.x operators and sources.
```

This happens only if I exit Activity "B" while my method is running even though it should get Disposed:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(disposableMain != null && !disposableMain.isDisposed()){
            disposableMain.dispose();
            Log.d("Disposable", "disposed");
        }
}
```

**Activity "B"**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Disposable disposableMain;
 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        myASYNC("DATA");
}

private void myASYNC(String data){
  Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                URL url1 = new URL(data);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("JSONTask failed", "task failed" + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observer<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                disposableMain = d;
            }
            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
                bitmapList.add(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {}
        });
}


@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(disposableMain != null && !disposableMain.isDisposed()){
            disposableMain.dispose();
            Log.d("Disposable", "disposed");
        }
}}
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

As the exception says, you're returning a `null` from your Callable.

First, remove the `try`-`catch` construct that returns a `null` from the `catch` block. You can handle exceptions in your observer's `onError`. (Note that the logging about "JSONTask" is also misleading.)

Second, `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` can also fail and return `null`. You can turn that into an exception with e.g. wrapping it in `Objects.requireNonNull()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when removed the try-catch I still get an error, and the app crashes, the same thing when both removed the try-catch and wrapped BitmapFactory.decodeStream() with Objects.requireNonNull().

Comment: That should be a different crash with a different stacktrace then.

Comment: The issue may be that I don't know how to handle these errors in the"OnError"

Comment: //java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference // when both of your tips are applied

Comment: All exceptions will be passed to the error consumer. Can you show us the modified code?